# PLupload only accepting some filters?

Tags: javascript, html, plupload, filefilter

I am using PLupload, it is using the HTML5 runtime.

In the filters it seems to only be accepting some filters,

E.g. if I have:

`filters:[{title:"Custom files", extensions:"pdf,png,gif,docx,doc,xls,xlsx"}]`

Then it filters so I can select pdf, png, and gif files, but not the docx+ ones.

It does not matter what order they are in. e.g.

`filters:[{title:"Custom files", extensions:"xlsx,pdf,docx,png,xls,gif,doc"}]` would yield the same result.

The input that is generated has the accept attribute with `application/pdf,image/png,image/gif,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` as it's value.

So, what is going on here, this issue is only present in the HTML5 version, the flash version filters correctly?

I would totally get it if the html5 version did not support filters, but it seems lt does... kind of?

Comment: I guess, concerning openxml documents, it might highly depend on the client OS and browser.  Does it work with IE9-10 on win 7-8 ?

Answer (score 2):

It only seems like it does because the "custom files" filter that Chrome implements happen to cover some of the files you have in your filter.

See [this thread](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/614).